# Problema al obtener un json de un servicio API Rest con AXIOS

Tags: javascript, rest, http, axios

La petición al servicio se realiza con axios mediante el siguiente script:

```
axios.get('http://datos.gijon.es/doc/transporte/busgijontr.json')
    .then(response => {
        let busPositions = {
            busPositions: []
        };
        let data = response.data;   
        let dataBusPositions = data.posiciones.posicion;
        dataBusPositions.forEach(bus => {
            busPositions.busPositions.push({
                idBus: bus.idautobus,
                registration: bus.matricula,
                model: bus.modelo,
                idLine: bus.idlinea,
                idJourney: bus.idtrayecto,
                coordinates: [bus.utmx, bus.utmy],
                lastStop: bus.idparada,
                nextStop: bus.idsiguienteparada,      
                timeToNextStop: bus.minutos,
                distanceToNextStop: bus.distancia 
            });
        });
        res.send({
            status: "success",
            busPositions: busPositions
        });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        res.send({
            status: "fail"
        });
    })
```

La url al servicio es esta: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](http://datos.gijon.es/doc/transporte/busgijontr.json)

El problema es que funciona a veces y de repente deja de hacerlo, saltándome este error cuando hago un console.log de data.posiciones:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'posicion' of undefined
at axios.get.then.response (D:\C7APIREST\GIS\getBusPositions.js:16:52)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

El json aparentemente está bien, ¿Alguien sabe por qué de repente falla al obtener data.posiciones.posicion si en el json sí existe?

---

Modificación: Sigue dando problemas. Este script se realiza en bucle para tener un refresco de la posición de los elementos en "tiempo real". ¿Podría ser que al estar editando y guardando, se vayan acumulando peticiones y puede que llegue un momento que rompa por tener tantas peticiones simultáneas?. No sé como podría ver cuántas peticiones está ejecutando AXIOS en un momento dado...

Comment: He probado tu código varias veces y me ha funcionado perfectamente.

Comment: @EugeniBejan he puesto en el forEach response.data.posicones.posicion directamente, sin asignarlo a variables, y parece que ahora funciona correctamente